# Upload a file in jsp and call that file in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, server, hana

Experts ,

Appreciate your insights here !

Basic question.

1. I have a jsp to upload a file and submitted the form.
2. I can retrieve the content from the jsp via servlet and using for my program.I am saying the file in c:\temp\test.txt directory.
   3.Code is perfectly working in local.

However when i upload the code in cloud..Its throwing 500 error saying the file path is not found. I know am doing some silly mistake here. can someone please advise how i can make this work in same via cloud?

Thanks. let me know if you need more details. Thanks.

Comment: `c:\temp\` - create path?

Comment: Are you actually uploading the file *content*? Or are you just uploading the file *path* and then you go read that file directly? Because that'll work locally, given that client and server is running on the same machine, but ...

Comment: Yes I upload the file in c:\\temp. this how am reading the file path   String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepathlatest)), "UTF-8");

Comment: This is perfectly working in local when i run the jsp. but not when i upload the code in cloud :(

Comment: here is the code how am storing the file from jsp... https://codeshare.io/5gV7YN